# subprocess.Popen and shell interpretation

Tags: python, bash

In my current setup, I have

```
command = "somecommand '%s'" % test
subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The reason why I have inner quotations '' is because I have spaces in test but it should be interpreted as 1 string (a path).

However, what I notice is that the command throws an error because it tries to use the path argument along with its own appended strings so we have ''path'/format' which throws an error.

However when I do somecommand 'path' it will work because the shell I'm guessing will interpret the string? Is this the correct reasoning?

My question is how do I deal with this case where the string needs to be interpreted in the shell before being run through Popen?

Comment: you might want `output = subprocess.check_output(["somecommand", test])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your command a list from the beginning:

```
command = ["somecommand", test]
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This will work even if `test` contains spaces because `subprocess.Popen()` passes each entry in the command list as a single argument.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good suggestion.  if `test` isn't a string, you might want to do something like `['somecommand',str(test)]`, but that's a minor nit.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `shlex.split` to split `command`:

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem is that `str.split` doesn't care if you've tried to put something in quotes -- It will split the string on whitespace no matter how much you quote things.  e.g.

```
>>> "foo 'bar baz'".split()
['foo', "'bar", "baz'"]
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("foo 'bar baz'")
['foo', 'bar baz']
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell isn't processing your command; each part of the list is being passed directly to some member of the `exec` family of system-level functions.

To have the shell process your command, you need to set the `shell` argument:

```
command = "somecommand '%s'" % test
subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but a better solution is to skip the shell, in which case you don't need to quote the value:

```
command = [somecommand, test]
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```